# Installing Air App for all users

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air

I am making an AIR app that is launched from the browser. When the user is changed the browser cannot launch the AIR app. Is there a way to set some param in the application.xml file or somewhere else to have the app be installed so that all users have access to it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, as I understand it, is that while AIR applications are by default installed as system-wide applications, the information needed to do SWF-badge based launching is based on files that are stored on a per-user basis. If this is the case then it makes sense why a user who has never actually run the AIR application can not launch the badge - the badge can't tell if the machine has the application installed. This would also mean that if the user has launched the AIR application it should then be able to be launched from the badge.

I don't have time right at this moment to prove this out, but based on my experiences with building custom badge installers I believe it to be true.